# Counting Letters in Word

Tags: c++

I am having troubles how to start creating program which counts letters in words in .txt file, and print it if letter number is bigger than 20.. Does someone know how to start or have some similar program to help me..Thank you

Comment: Rather than the number 20, you want letters that are *printable* and not a space.  See the function [isprint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint).

Comment: This is a very open ended question.  What have you tried, and what problems have you run into?  Also, I don't know what "letter number is bigger than 20" means.

Comment: I need to count only letters in words and if the word have >  20 letters than print that word in out.txt file...

Comment: I haven't started because i don't know how to start ...

Comment: Which data types/data structures do you know that can hold multiple characters? Which text input/output functions/operators do you know?

Answer (score 0):

In general,I start programs by:

```
#include <iostream>

void Pause();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "My program\n";

    Pause();
    return 0;
}

void Pause()
{
  std::cout << "\n\nPaused. Press ENTER to continue.\n";
  std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
}
```

After I get the above working, I add content.
Assuming the ASCII encoding, you could make some assumptions:

```
int counts[256] = {0};
char c;
while (my_file.read(&c, 1))
{
    counts[c]++;
}
```

The above loop will count all occurrences of the letters in the text file.  The next task would be to print the data:

```
for (int i = ' ' + 1; i < 127; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "'" << ((char) i) << "': " << counts[i] << \n;
}
```

This will print out the counts for all printable characters, starting with the character after a space.

This is a popular beginning assignment, so you should be able to find more examples on the internet.

**Edit 1: For counts of words**
The `std::string` and `std::map` are your friends.

```
  std::string word;
  std::map<std::string, int> database;
  while (my_file >> word)
  {
     std::map<std::string, int>::iterator iter;
     iter = database.find(word);
     if (iter != database.end())
     {
         map[word]++;
     }
     else
     {
         map[word] = 1;
     }
  }
```

The above loop builds a database of [word, count] pairs.  If the word exists, the count is incremented.

The next part is to iterate through the database and only print the words that have a length > 20.  This is left as an exercise for the reader.